# A work problem on complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

Let be  $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function satisfying

a) $\lim_{z\to \infty} |f(z)|=\infty$;

b) $f(\mathbb{C})$ is open.

Prove that $f(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}$.

Can someone give some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

- Using the fact that $\lim_{z\to \infty }|f(z)|=\infty $, you can prove that $f(\mathbb C)$ is sequentially closed, and thus closed.
- Since $f(\mathbb C)$ is open as well, using the fact that $\mathbb C$ is connected gives you the wished result.

Comment: Ok! This is not exacly a hint but I'm gratefull anyway

Comment: @Eduardo: I updated my answer. Sorry to have not given you a hint the first time.